# How to add space in my navigation bar's right border using html and css only?

Tags: html, css

I'm having troubles adding a little space in my navigation bar. This is for my activity in school please help

here is a picture [navbarpic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saNpH.png)

my html and css so far is

```
 .nav .container  ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 18px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav li{
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}


<body>
    <div>
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="container">
                <ul>
                    <li ><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">OUR SERVICES</a></li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is my code so far. I would appreciate any help for this . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can add some padding to the navigation items

Answer (score 1):

You can add few padding on the right side of the `li` element for the navigation items:

```css
.nav .container  ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 18px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav li{
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    padding-right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="nav">
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li ><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OUR SERVICES</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it work... but my nav move at the banner side..I'll try to find ways how to fix the postiion.. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You can use "**pseudo**" element to make right border with `position: absolute` style. it will never break your layout and you can move any white from li.
Hope this will help you :)

```css
.nav .container  ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 18px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav li:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    right: -15px;
    top: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="nav">
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li ><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OUR SERVICES</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```